# Change Magento 1.9 Availability message depends on qty

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to change the Availability message in product page depends on qty. So far I tried a couple of methods but no change at all. One of them is :

```
<?php if($product_page_type == 'sticky_left_right' || $product_page_type == 'wide_grid'): ?>
            <?php if (($_product->isAvailable()) && (id($_product->getQty() <= 0))): ?>
                <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php elseif (($_product->isAvailable()) && (id($_product->getQty() == 0))): ?>
                <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo "hello" ?></span></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($sku = $_product->getSku()): ?>
                <p class="sku"><?php echo $this->__('SKU:') ?> <span><?php echo $sku; ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

But changing qty of product not change at all in front end.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was editing the wrong file. The changes should be made in base folder catalog/view/type/default.phtml. Now it is working.